# Не получается десериализовать приходящую json-строку

Tags: c#, json

Приходит json-строка:

```
"[{\"Name\":\"1\",\"Date\":\"2017-03-16\"},{\"Name\":\"2\",\"Date\":\"2017-03-16\"},{\"Name\":\"3\",\"Date\":\"2017-03-16\"}]"
```

Пытаюсь десериализовать

```
RootObjectCount newN = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectCount>(json);
```

Выходит ошибка:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type '1.Form_Main+RootObjectCount' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Если убираю квадратные скобки, то выходит такая ошибка:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 1, position 32.
```

Что с этой строкой сделать, чтобы получилось десериализовать?

```
public class RootObjectCount
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Date { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Покажите `RootObjectCount`. Кавычки должны быть снаружи `"[{...`

Comment: @Igor, исправила - очепятка

Comment: Спасибо. Покажите `RootObjectCount`.

Comment: @Igor, добавила RootObjectCount

Comment: Ещё чтобы получать классы исходя из json можно воспользоваться сервисом что-то вроде [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: @Anxis, да, я использую этот сервис, очень удобно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В строке массив объектов, так что десериализовывать нужно тоже в список или массив.

```
List<RootObjectCount> newN = 
  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObjectCount>>(json);
```